# how to build a function to change field color based on parameters

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I set a function to change the field color

html:

```
<input id="nameInput" type="text" onfocus="backColor();">
```

javascript:

```
function backColor() {

document.getElementById("nameInput").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
```

but Then I tried to make different function that will include parameters and change the color based on the but it obviously didn't worked. How do I do that?

html:

```
<input id="nameInput" type="text" onfocus="backColor(nameInput, 'yellow');">
```

javascript:

```
  function backColor(id, color) {
     var idInput = document.getElementById(id);
     var color;
     idInput.style.backgroundColor = color;
     return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

missed single quotes while passing name if ID

```js
  function backColor(id, color) {
     var idInput = document.getElementById(id);
     var color;
     idInput.style.backgroundColor = color;
     return;
}
```

```html
<input id="nameInput" type="text" onfocus="backColor('nameInput', 'yellow');">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may just be missing some quotes around your id:

```
<input id="nameInput" type="text" onfocus="backColor('nameInput', 'yellow');">
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You may use currying:

```
 function colorChooser(id, color){
   const el = document.getElementById(id);

   return function colorCallback(){
    el.style.backgroundColor = color;
   }
 }
```

So you can do:

```
 document.getElementById("input").onclick = colorChooser("sth", "yellow");
```